# Encryption type symfony2

Tags: encryption, passwords

I have this password : cJU6fIvqSrHJq8ErBo0mU9fFjzPdSl/94iZyzX/VZ9RJ+GLm3PopuABNopq4UcqcMJTPOBu8KHadfcXl7DEE4Q==

and I want to know the used encryption type. I got this password with the salt from a database used by a script coded with symfony2.

the developer said that he used the sha512 encryption but I think that there is another encode method used.

Thank you,

Comment: Why do you think that a different method was used, and what do you need that knowledge for? (And: hashing isn't encryption!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to hash the used password with the same salt and I didn't get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

you are right that there is further encoding, as this a base64 encoding of what is probably a hash output.  the decode of the base64 string into a hex string is:

```
70953a7c8bea4ab1c9abc12b068d2653d7c58f33dd4a5ffde22672cd7fd567d449f862e6dcfa29b8004da29ab851ca9c3094cf381bbc28769d7dc5e5ec3104e1
```

which is odd because its 128 bytes/1024 bits long, compared to sha512 which is 64 bytes/512 bits.  It may be that the salt has been appended to the hash or something like that.  Compare your sha512 hashing with the above hex string and see if it matches some part of it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
My hashed password is : `c3682b2b2adc1afc0e1e300a7f27c00e39121cc1fd1eed8b3ee9a701125465cf3a6c6bb8ecc9b4ea6c2e2d01b75c9a49f66f5f3a4bc196f449782ae9cb121d6e`
It's strange :/ there is no resemblance